# How to add onClick event on a dynamically created button

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to append a block of element everytime I receive a message.
It is basically a simple chat.

So every time a new chat is received , the new message will be appended to the div.

But how I'm not able to add an onClick event to it
This is the line :  `<button class="likeBtn" onClick={this.pointButton}><i class="far fa-heart"></i></button>`

```
let msgLeft = document.getElementById("msg-left");
if (this.state.username === data.username) {
msgLeft.insertAdjacentHTML(
"beforeend",
`<div class="main-c-container-right">
<div class="c-image"></div>
<div class="c-text-container">
<div class="c-name">
${data.username}
</div>
<div class="c-text"> 
<div class="c-pointer"></div>
${data.message.replace(/\n/g, "<br>")}
</div> 
<div class="c-time">
${currentTime} 
</div> 
<button class="likeBtn" onClick={this.pointButton}><i class="far fa-heart"></i></button>
</div>
</div>`
);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically what you need to do is to hold the array of elements somewhere (local state, redux,etc..) and display the array of elements on the JSX.

If you need to add a new element to this array, you just need to update this value with the new element and React will know how to re-render everything again.

You don't need to directly manipulate the DOM while using React.

Comment: But if i store it in an array wont the entire component re-rendered when i receive a new message ?

Comment: Yes, it will but is there a problem for you now? Are you facing perfomance issues?

There are strategies to avoid the re-render the component tho

Comment: Yeah the thing is , It is a continues chat for like half n hour , So if the array keeps looping and re rendering the component then there will be performance issue , That too it is a group chat consisting of 10 people . So is there a way to avoid the re-rendering ?